# how to solve this error "org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not create file" in kettle

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

i am using `kettle 3.2`. i have a requirement like i need to write `CSV file` based on the data from the `another table`. As the number of `rows increases` the `CSV files` also `increases`. i mean if i have 2 rows then the file will created like 1st row data in one.csv and second data in two.csv

The design which i made works fine up to 650 rows but after 700 it is showing the error

```
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA,
 build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) : Unexpected error :
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA,
 build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) :
 org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:  2012/12/31 14:21:27 -
 CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA, build 10572 from
 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) : Error opening new file :
 org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not create file
 "file:///home/admin/Desktop/data-integration3.2/CT_1056800_20121231_142127.CSV".
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA,
 build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) :  2012/12/31
 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA, build 10572
 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) :    at
 org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutput.openNewFile(TextFileOutput.java:654)
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA,
 build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) :    at
 org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutput.setDataWriterForFilename(TextFileOutput.java:187)
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA,
 build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) :    at
 org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutput.processRow(TextFileOutput.java:163)
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA,
 build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) :    at
 org.pentaho.di.trans.step.BaseStep.runStepThread(BaseStep.java:2889)
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - CSV FILE OUTPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA,
 build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) :    at
 org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfileoutput.TextFileOutput.run(TextFileOutput.java:849)
 2012/12/31 14:21:27 - EXTRACTION_FOR_CUSTOMER - ERROR (version
 3.2.0-GA, build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
```

please help me to solve this. thanks in advance

Comment: Does this reliably happen between 650 and 700? Maybe it has something to do with exceeding the number of open file handles a process can have on your system. The solution would then be to change your code to ensure that Kettle closes them.

Comment: Why are you using Kettle 3.2? It's very very old.. I'd try the latest and greatest as well, shouldnt take 5 minutes to give it a try. maybe 3.2 was leaking handles as Gordon suggests..

Comment: Sorry i cannot able to change the version. Am working for a customer who is already using 3.2 version(In which they have all their jobs running) and they are not willing to change the version. so i need to fix it in the 3.2 version.

Comment: I checked in kettle 4.3 also but the same error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. I solved this using **Modify java script** object for creating large number of CSV files (>8000). I used inbuilt function

**appendToFile(filepath,content)**

Thank you for all your support